# Extjs Date Time Picker, HighLight particular Date instead of system date

Tags: extjs

How to highlight the particular date in extjs calendar(Date Time Picker) control,

As default it will highlight the system date when it shows. I need to set highlight date as sql server date since it will be different.

Is there any property or override method to change the highlight date?

Note: Only highlight in the calendar not to set that value to text box.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to do. What `textfield` are you talking about? Unless you're talking about the `datefield` control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not mention which version of ExtJS you're using, but I'm assuming 3.x.

What you're asking is not very easy. You would need to override the `update` method of `Ext.DateField` class, as highlighting is done in that function.

The cell that has the current date is assigned the `x-date-today` style class, which adds the red border around the current date etc. So if you just want to get rid of the highlighting altogether, consider overriding the style definition of that class.

**UPDATE:** Look for this line of code especially:

```
today = new Date().clearTime().getTime(),
```

A bit further down from there the `today` variable is used in `setCellClass` function to determine whether the chosen date is "today" (and if it should be highlighted). So you would want to assign a different value to the `today` variable, in your override method.

Comment: hi,thnk for the tip, i will try on it and get back to u,
and i am using 3.x version only

Comment: tommi,
     can u specify in which function and the file(js/css), in which they are assigning the currentdate to that variable x-date-today

Comment: Added some more details. The file to look at is probably ext-all.js.

Comment: thnk tommy ...it works fine..

i need to work, how to set the sql time to that variable on initailize.

any way thank u.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is: **How do I set a different date in the calendar of a DateField control?**

If you initialise the `DateField` control with your custom *date*, the buildin `DatePicker` will use that value as the highlighted date.

```
{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    value: '2011-02-28'
}
```

See the source file for `Ext\src\widgets\form\DateField.js` in the following method:

```
/**
 * @method onTriggerClick
 * @hide
 */
// private
// Implements the default empty TriggerField.onTriggerClick function to display the DatePicker
onTriggerClick : function(){
    if(this.disabled){
        return;
    }
    if(this.menu == null){
        this.menu = new Ext.menu.DateMenu({
            hideOnClick: false,
            focusOnSelect: false
        });
    }
    this.onFocus();
    Ext.apply(this.menu.picker,  {
        minDate : this.minValue,
        maxDate : this.maxValue,
        disabledDatesRE : this.disabledDatesRE,
        disabledDatesText : this.disabledDatesText,
        disabledDays : this.disabledDays,
        disabledDaysText : this.disabledDaysText,
        format : this.format,
        showToday : this.showToday,
        minText : String.format(this.minText, this.formatDate(this.minValue)),
        maxText : String.format(this.maxText, this.formatDate(this.maxValue))
    });
    this.menu.picker.setValue(this.getValue() || new Date()); <--- LOOK HERE!!!
    this.menu.show(this.el, "tl-bl?");
    this.menuEvents('on');
},
```

But again, I'm not sure I understand your question :)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find anything in the documentation about initialising the DatePicker control with a preselected date.

But you could do something like the following:

```
xtype: 'datepicker',
listeners: 
{
    render: function(control) {
        control.setValue(new Date('1/10/2007'));
    }
}
```

I don't know which event is most suitable for this kind of initialisation, but the `render` event does work for me :)

Happy Ext'ing.

Comment: hi chau : setValue method set that value to that textfield..but i need to highlight only on the calender control.

Comment: hi, i am using date field control only,but they use base as DatePicker as you mentioned. how we set "today" to highlight the date in DatePicker as tommi mentioned from datefield.

Comment: @Vineth: Isn't that what I described in my other answer to this question?

Comment: view the link for better understanding :::http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?21566898aa.jpg

Comment: @Vineth: Exactly. If you post the server date into the datefield, the highlighted date will be the server date. I know that the datefield won't be empty then, but you'll get the wanted effect.